# Pegar valor no Array chunk

Tags: php, array

Tnho 12 times cadastrados em uma tabela e quero dividi-los em 3 grupos. Então recebo esses times em forma de array e uso o `array_chunk` para dividi-los, que irá formar os 3 grupos de 4 times que quero.

Mas não estou conseguindo acessar o `NAME_TEAM`, ja tentei várias formas e não consigo. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Veja como fica montado o array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 222
                    [name_team] => Atletico GO
                    [name_coach] => Afonso de Carvalo
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 223
                    [name_team] => Atletico MG
                    [name_coach] => Levir culpi
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 224
                    [name_team] => Palmeiras
                    [name_coach] => Cuca
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 225
                    [name_team] => Flamengo
                    [name_coach] => Zé Ricardo
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 226
                    [name_team] => Corinthians
                    [name_coach] => José da Silva
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 227
                    [name_team] => Santos
                    [name_coach] => Dorival Junior
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 228
                    [name_team] => Grêmio
                    [name_coach] => Renato Portallupi
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 229
                    [name_team] => Ponte Preta
                    [name_coach] => Ernando
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 242
                    [name_team] => Vasco
                    [name_coach] => Milton Santos
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 245
                    [name_team] => Botafogo
                    [name_coach] => Jair Ventura
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 246
                    [name_team] => São Paulo
                    [name_coach] => Rogério Ceni
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id_t] => 247
                    [name_team] => Cruzeiro
                    [name_coach] => Mano Menezes
                    [active_team] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Como você tentou acessar? poderia colocar o código

Comment: estou usando assim e ele esta imprimindo apenas alguns:

$array = array_chunk( $teams, 4 );

$f = 0;
foreach ( $array as $team ) {
  
  echo $team[$f]->name_team;

  $f++;

}

Comment: consegui dessa forma:
    $f = 0;
foreach ( $array as $team ) {
  
  for ($i=0; $i < 4 ; $i++) { 
  
        echo $team[$f][$i]->name_team;

  }

  $f++;

}

Comment: obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

Tenta:

```
$obj = $teuArray[0][0];

$nomeTime = $obj->name_team;
```

Comment: tentei do jeiro que disse e não funcionou, estou tentando assim e pegou alguns:
$array = array_chunk( $teams, 4 );

$f = 0;
foreach ( $array as $team ) {
  
  echo $team[$f]->name_team;

  $f++;

}

Comment: consegui dessa forma:
    $f = 0;
foreach ( $array as $team ) {
  
  for ($i=0; $i < 4 ; $i++) { 
  
        echo $team[$f][$i]->name_team;

  }

  $f++;

}

Comment: obrigado pela atenção

Comment: À qualquer hora, amigo. Se o post ajudou vota nele aí. :D